# Concatenating observables is not acting as required - RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have 2 Observables that do 2 different jobs that returns their observables

First one : **SyncDoctors** for getting doctor list from my WebService

```
public Observable<List<Doctor>> SyncDoctors(){
    Observable<List<Doctor>> observable = MyWebService.getInterface().GetAllDoctors();
    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Doctor>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Doctor> doctors) {
                    if(doctors.size() == 0){
                        logger.debug("No Coming Doctors");
                        return;
                    }

                    DoctorDao doctorDao = MyApplication.getDaoSession().getDoctorDao();
                    doctorDao.deleteAll();

                    doctorDao.insertInTx(doctors);

                    logger.debug("Doctors are synced successfully to the database");
                    logger.info(doctors.size()+" doctors have been added to database");
                }
            });
    return observable;
}
```

**Second Observable** for getting patients list from my webservice

```
public Observable<List<Patients>> SyncPatients(){
    Observable<List<Patients>> observable = MyWebService.getInterface().GetAllPatients();
    observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Patients>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Patients> patients) {
                    if(patients.size() == 0){
                        logger.debug("No Coming Patients");
                        return;
                    }

                    PatientDao PatientDao = MyApplication.getDaoSession().getPatientDao();
                    patientDao.deleteAll();

                    PatientDao.insertInTx(Patients);

                    logger.debug("Patients are synced successfully to the database");
                    logger.info(Patients.size()+" Patients have been added to database");
                }
            });
    return observable;
}
```

Now i want to sync both doctors and patients lists and after both syncs finish, i want to show it on the screen of the tablet:

I have function called **SyncAll**

```
public void SyncAll(){

    Observable<List<Doctor>> doctorsObservable = SyncDoctors();
    Observable<List<Patient>> patientsObservable = SyncPatients();

    Observable.concat(doctorsObservable, patientsObservable)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // Here the code to show on ListView
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    logger.debug("On SyncAll Next!!!");
                }
            });
}
```

onNext functions I save the list of doctors and list of patients to the database.

now when I call `SyncDoctors()` alone, it works
also when I call `SyncPatients()` alone, it works as well.

when I call `SyncAll()` the Doctors and Patients are not being saved to the database.

**The Question is why the `SyncDoctors()` and `SyncPatients()` observables' onNext functions are called when I call `SyncAll()` !!**

Comment: Try to add e.printStackTrace inside `onError` in `SyncAll` and see what is happening.

Comment: @R.Zagórski there is not error, the problem is that SyncDoctor's onNext is not being called, instead, SyncAll's onNext getting called 2 times !

Comment: Assuming, that all your DAO operations are synchronous, are you sure want to do all of them on main thread?

Comment: @marwinXXII In the answer i already got the idea of not doing it on main thread, this line was added in the answer `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you activate chain by calling .subscribe() in

```
Observable<List<Doctor>> doctorsObservable = SyncDoctors();
Observable<List<Patient>> patientsObservable = SyncPatients();
```

You first create observable, then subscribe to it of SyncDoctors() and SyncPatients();
After that you return this Observable, but web response is triggered upon observable creation.
To solve that use .map():

```
public Observable<List<Doctor>> SyncDoctors(){
        final Observable<List<Doctor>> observable = MyWebService.getInterface().GetAllDoctors();
        observable.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                // in your code you performed db io on main thread, here it is fixed
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(new Func1<List<Doctor>, List<Doctor>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Doctor> call(List<Doctor> doctors) {
                        if(doctors.size() == 0){
                            logger.debug("No Coming Doctors");
                            return;
                        }

                        DoctorDao doctorDao = MyApplication.getDaoSession().getDoctorDao();
                        doctorDao.deleteAll();

                        doctorDao.insertInTx(doctors);

                        logger.debug("Doctors are synced successfully to the database");
                        logger.info(doctors.size()+" doctors have been added to database");
                        return doctors;
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        // Notice: use Observable.defer() or you'll get the same result all the tim
        return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<List<Doctor>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<Doctor>> call() {
                return observable;
            }
        });
    }
```

You should not use .concat(), because it executes chain elements consequently. use .zip().first() intead.

There is also one issue: you perform db operations on main thread.
move chain to main thread after db update

Version with .zip:

```
void syncAll(){
    Observable<List<Doctor>> doctorsObservable = SyncDoctors();
    Observable<List<Patient>> patientsObservable = SyncPatients();
    Observable.zip(doctorsObservable, patientsObservable, new Func2<List<Doctor>, List<Patient>, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(List<Doctor> doctors, List<Patient> patients) {
            return true;
        }
    })
            .first()
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                    logger.debug("On SyncAll Next!!!");
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: `zip` is probably not going to work here since you can't guarantee similar length of doctors and patients which could drop items. If you use `zip(obs1.list(), obs2.list())` you're missing the whole point of using observables and might as well use a blocking observable and do things synchronously.

Comment: Both methods return lists of items, but .concat() waits for first observable to complete, then second and so on.. .zip() start everything at the same time and waits until all results is there.

Comment: Yup. Missed that fact.

Comment: Please can you put the implementation of the zip().first ?

Comment: instead of doing all the kerfuffle, given that you don't care about the return types at all, you should be able to use `Observable<?>` as the types, then just `Observable.merge(doctorsObservable, patientsObservable).ignoreElements()` and proceed based on the completion.

Comment: It is possible, that some items from Doctors or Patients might be dropped when using `zip` if these sequences have different number of items.
`merge` or (`concat`) + `ignoreElements` is a correct way.

Comment: Both sequeces has only one value- list of items

Comment: Then I think, you should leave only second version with `zip`, because first one is confusing and contains redundant code.